# DBIx::Class select from a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbix-class

I'm trying to write the following SQL query using DBIx::Class:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT username, DENSE_RANK () OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(username) DESC) FROM myTable GROUP BY username) AS topUsers WHERE username='myUsername';
```

`myTable` consists of only two rows, one being the username and the other one representing an achievement of the user. The subquery is supposed to assign a rank to each user and the main query selects the rank of `myUser`.

I'm having some issues in translating this to DBIx::Class so I would appreciate some help!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subqueries in DBIx::Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312506/subqueries-in-dbixclass)

Answer (score 0):

You should define your query as view. See [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Manual::Cookbook#Arbitrary-SQL-through-a-custom-ResultSource)

After that you can:

```
$schema->resultset( 'YourView' )->search
```

This will generate SQL:

```
select * from ( <your query here> )
```